# У меня везде(сколько не исправляла) идет ошибка segmentation fault. Почему?

Tags: c, указатели, типы, segmentation-fault

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include <string.h>

void    *ft_memset(void *dest, int c, size_t n)
{
    char *str;

    str = (char*)dest;

    if (!str)
        return(NULL);
    while ((n-1) > 0)
    {
        *str = (char)(c);
        str++;
        n--;
    }
    *str = '\0';
    return(dest);
}

int main(void)
{
    char *dest = "uj";

    printf("%s", (char*)(ft_memset(dest, 4, 6)));
}
```

Comment: У вас `dest` указывает на константу, а они размещаются в области памяти, защищенной от записи.

Comment: Не стоит писать в литерал, и уже тем более - за его пределами...

Comment: а вы не объясните подробнее, где такая ошибка?

Comment: Просто сделайте dest массивом char необходимой длины)

Answer (score 1):

`char * dest = "uj";` - указатель на строку, которая храниться в программе, и которую менять нельзя.

`char dest[] = "uj";` - это уже будет новая строка в стеке, которую можно менять.